# iOS - Importing data into CoreData

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, import, seed

I need to import some data in the db of an iOS (7+) app.

As I'm working with Coredata the best way seems to create a seed db: https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/importing-large-data-sets-into-core-data/
This means I have to create a second project (eg: desktop app) which takes care to create and populate the db.

My first concern is: should the db model of this project be the same of the app one? Therefore if the app has a db with many entities, the entire structure must be replicated in the model of second project, and for any future update the two structures must be kept alike.
Am I correct?

This seems quite demanding to be done and maintained, moreover the process of finding and copying the seed sqlite file is not straightforward.

That said, as I need to import about 80k entries into a single table, what about including a csv file in the iOS app and import all the data at the first launch?

Thanks for any hint,
DAN

Answer (score 0):

### Whether the db model should be the same : It doesn't need to

`CoreData` is not db it's so you can have more flexible model than traditional db

If you choose to maintain different model than the one your server use or returned by `API`, you can use intermediary model before you save to your CoreData.

I personally use [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle).

So the structure will be `CoreData` <->`Mantle`<->`API`.

This will give you greater flexibility because you can receive any structure from the API and use `Mantle` to manage the structure you are using in your app.

**ps: generally, you don't want to change the data model often. If your data model keep changing, it might be a time to rethink about the structure**

### To import the entries you can use JSON file.

1. Add the JSON file to your project
2. When the app launch for the first time, deserialize the JSON file, loop through it and create new entity for each item in JSON

Be mind this might take a long time if you have 80k entries

[This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated) show you exactly what you need to do

Comment: The tutorial you suggest explains exactly the scenario I've described above: using a separate utility project to create a seed db (and not fill in the app db at first launch). My concern is about keeping the two models alike for any future update. Supposing the iOS app has a model with entities A, B, C and D, even if only D needs to be pre-filled, the core data model of the utility project must have the same exact structure with all the four tables. Moreover adding a new entity - E - to the app would require it to be added to the utility project model too.

Comment: Hi @DAN indeed the easiest is to keep both the model (server and app) the same. Yes it is a hassle to manage. I update my answer.